# How to Remove the invoice & Shipment link from my Account pages?

Tags: magento-1.9, customer-account

How can I remove `invoices & shipment` links from my `account/myorder` page ? I am using Magento ver. 1.9.2

Comment: I had a quite similar issue in **Magento 2**. You can see my answer [here](http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/144381/38275).

Comment: Magento 1 or Magento 2 ? Please don't use different version tags as answers migh differ depending on your version.

Comment: This is not a duplicate as this is for Magento 1.9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find it in

> app/design/frontend/Yourheme/default/layout/sales.xml

```
<sales_order_view translate="label">
    <reference name="sales.order.info">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="sales"><name>invoice</name><path>*/*/invoice</path><label>Invoices</label></action>
        <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="sales"><name>shipment</name><path>*/*/shipment</path><label>Shipments</label></action>
    </reference>
</sales_order_view>
```

Comment out this code.

Or if you want remove links from all actions then

Search all matching code

```
    <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="sales"><name>invoice</name><path>*/*/invoice</path><label>Invoices</label></action>
    <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="sales"><name>shipment</name><path>*/*/shipment</path><label>Shipments</label></action>
```

and comment out in whole xml code

Comment: I have commented these lines on section  <label>Customer My Account Order View</label>  but invoices & shipments links still showing

Comment: check in this tag <sales_order_view translate="label">

Comment: You have comment wrong section check properly my answer.

Comment: I have commented these lines in section <sales_order_view translate="label">
        <label>Customer My Account Order View</label>

Comment: Add your complete sales.xml code to in your question then i will revert to you with proper modification.

Comment: Or you can search Invoices and Shipments in you xml and all action comment out. then check it.

Comment: Success or not. Are your getting my point.

Comment: <sales_order_view translate="label">
<label>Customer My Account Order View</label>
<sales_order_invoice translate="label">
<label>Customer My Account Order Invoice View</label>
 <sales_order_shipment translate="label">
 <label>Customer My Account Order Shipment View</label>
I have commented lines in all these sections but not working

Comment: Add complete code of you sales.xml file with file path.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48118/discussion-between-aks-and-s-h-patel).

Answer (score 1):

You need to comment or remove the below code from following xml file:

app/design/frontend/Your_theme/default/layout/sales.xml

```
<action method="addLink" translate="label" module="sales"><name>invoice</name><path>*/*/invoice</path><label>Invoices</label></action>
<action method="addLink" translate="label" module="sales"><name>shipment</name><path>*/*/shipment</path><label>Shipments</label></action>
```

Answer (score -1):

in your `sales.xml` add below code

`app/design/frontend/YourPackge/YourTheme/layout/sales.xml`

```
 <sales_order_view translate="label">
  <reference name="sales.order.info">
     <remove name="invoice"> </remove>
     <remove name="shipment"> </remove> 
  </reference>
 </sales_order_view>
```