# Remove the invoice link from the customer account page in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, customer, invoice, customer-account

I would like to remove the **Invoices** link from the customer account page in Magento 2:

[image]

I tried to search it in templates and layout files but no luck.

Someone know how to do?

Answer (score 3):

Found it.

Create this file within your theme dir:

`<theme_dir>/Magento_Sales/layout/sales_order_info_links.xml`

Then you can remove links with this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
  <body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">

      <!-- <referenceBlock name="sales.order.info.links" remove="true" /> -->
      <!-- <referenceBlock name="sales.order.info.links.information" remove="true" /> -->
      <referenceBlock name="sales.order.info.links.invoice" remove="true" />
      <!-- <referenceBlock name="sales.order.info.links.creditmemo" remove="true" /> -->

    </referenceContainer>
  </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Might also be good to add this to `sales_order_guest_info_links.xml`

Answer (score 2):

Write below code in given file path

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

```
<referenceBlock name="sales.order.info.links.invoice" remove="true" />
```